# Show Product Price including tax at product view page

Tags: magento

I have made the settings to display product price, at product view page ,inclusive of tax.
I made the changes in admin like:
Display Product Prices In Catalog : including Tax

But the prices are still showing exclusive of tax at product view page.

Comment: have to try to refresh cache or reindex data?

Comment: I refreshed Cache and reindexed data but no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to System->Configuration->Sales(left side)->Tax. Then in Calculation settings-> Catalog Prices Make it to INCLUDING TAX. Now save the configuration and go to the Catalog->Manage Products. Edit the required product. In the PRICES tab, it has to show the tax value below to the field where we enter price for the product. For eg: See image below. [image]

Here my product price is $550. Down to it is shows the value that included of TAX also(If you enable option as explained above, then the tax value shows as in the image). So TAX value is also included in $550 only.

Comment: I made the settings in the admin for including Tax .But the problem was that i was not selecting the proper store from admin.

Comment: Happy to see that you got solved the issue... Cheers :)